# AMD FX-6300 no reboot from UEFI and OS but fine first POST

Tags: boot, reboot

I have recently converted my Gaming PC into a home server that I am looking to host a website on. 
For that, I put my motherboard (Asrock Extreme3 990FX) with my AMD FX-6300 into a new case and installed Ubuntu Server on it.

However, while setting up I noticed a problem: My system fails to reboot when saving settings in the UEFI or just rebooting from the OS. The System does not POST after any kind of software or hardware reset, not even from the reset button on the front panel connector. This happens with every graphics card i installed in it, so we can rule that out.

The system posts fine from a cold boot without any errors. Where should I start troubleshooting?

Comment: So the system boots, but only, if it's a cold boot?

Comment: @Ramhound exactly.

Comment: I assume you don't have another GPU you can try?

Comment: I have a Nvidia GT710 laying around that causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplugging the mechanical hard drive from power fixes this problem.